# Simple Random Walk, Generating Function and Markov Property

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

My problem is about a simple random walk $ X_{n} $ with transition probabilities $ P_{i,i + 1} = p $ and $ P_{i, i-1} = 1-p $. I must prove that $ [\mathbb{E}_{1}(s^{T})]^2 = \mathbb{E}_{2}(s^{T}) $, where $ T = \min \{ n \ge 0: X_{n} = 0\} $. I would appreciate any hints. I've thought about it a lot but can't find a way to do it. I know I must apply the Markov property at some point but no more.

Comment: Is $s$ just a real number?

Comment: Yes. $E_{x}(s^{T})$ is the generating function

Comment: Move one step, with prob. $1-p$ it goes left and $T = 1$ and with probability $p$ it goes right and $T = T' + 1$ where $T'$ has the same definition as $T$ but for a random walk starting at $x = 2.$ In symbols: Notice that $\mathbf{E}_1(s^T) = \big( (1 - p) + p\mathbf{E}_2(s^T) \big) s.$ Can you get a pattern?

Comment: In fact I understand that argument well but I don't see how to use it for my specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to see what Will M. said if you rephrase the problem a little.
Let's define
$$T_i^j = \min \{n \ge 0 : X_0=i, X_n=j\}$$
Note that $E(s^{T_i^{i-1}}) = E(s^{T_1^0}) = E(s^T) \text{, for every $i\in Z$}$, which is the generator function of the first passage time for $1$ step to the left.

Now for the exercise, it's easy to prove that:
$$E(s^T | X_0=1) = s (1-p) + psE(s^T|X_0=2)$$
What you then have to note is that $E(s^T|X_0=1)^2 = E(s^T|X_0=2)$ since the first passage time for $2$ step to the left means that you first have to step $1$ to the left, then another. More precisely:
$$T_i^{i-2} = T_{i}^{i-1} + T_{i-1}^{i-2}$$
$T_{i}^{i-1}$ and $T_{i-1}^{i-2}$ are independent, so
$$E(s^{T_i^{i-2}}) = E(s^{T_{i}^{i-1} + T_{i-1}^{i-2}}) = E(s^{T_{i}^{i-1}}) E(s^{T_{i-1}^{i-2}}) = {E(s^T)}^2$$

You can substitute it to the above equation, and solve it, and you get:
$$ E(s^T) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^2}}{2ps} $$

Comment: Thanks, I understood perfectly